# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{- x²} dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, error-function

I have tried to evaluate the integral
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{- x^2} dx.$$
I used integration by parts but I did not succeed. Wolfram Alpha says that is convergent and it is equal to: $\frac \pi 2 \text{erf}({\frac 12})$ .

Is there any simple way for evaluate it?

Comment: Do it via the convolution theorem for the Fourier transform.

Comment: A simplified version of Cameron Williams’ suggestion is that you can consider $$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{ixt}\,dt$$ and then change the order of integration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have that
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-x^2} dx
&=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\int_{0}^\infty x^{2k}e^{-x^2} dx\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\int_{0}^\infty t^{k-1/2}e^{-t} dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\Gamma(k+1/2)}{(2k+1)!}
\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\cdot(1/2)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)k!}=
\frac{\pi}{2}\text{erf}(1/2).\end{align}$$
For the last step see [the Taylor series of erf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Taylor_series).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a slightly longer method (compared to @Robert Z's slick series solution approach) that uses Feynman's trick of differentiating under the integral sign.

Let 
$$I(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (ax)}{x} e^{-x^2} \, dx, \quad a > 0.$$
Note that $I(0) = 0$ and we are required to find $I(1)$.

Differentiating $I(a)$ with respect to the parameter $a$ gives
$$I'(a) = \int_0^\infty \cos (ax) e^{-x^2} \, dx. \tag1$$

On integrating (1) by parts leads to
$$I'(a) = \frac{2}{a} \int_0^\infty x e^{-x^2} \sin (ax) \, dx.$$

Also, differentiating (1) again with respect to the parameter $a$ yields
$$I''(a) = -\int_0^\infty x e^{-x^2} \sin (ax) \, dx = -\frac{a}{2} I'(a).$$
If we set $u(a) = I'(a)$ the above second-order differential equation can be reduced to the following first-order differential equation
$$u'(a) = -\frac{a}{2} u(a).$$
Solving yields
$$u(a) = I'(a) = K e^{-a^2/4}, \tag1$$
where $K$ is a constant to be determined. To find this constant setting $a = 0$ in $I'(a)$ leads to
$$I'(0) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \cdot \text{erf} (\infty) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$ 
So on setting $a= 0$ in (1) we find $K = \sqrt{\pi}/2$. Thus
$$I'(a) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-a^2/4}.$$

Now as $I(0) = 0$, we have
$$I(1) = \int_0^1 I'(a) \, da = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_0^1 e^{-a^2/4} \, da.$$
Enforcing a substitution of $a \mapsto 2a$ leads to
$$I(1) = \sqrt{\pi} \int_0^{1/2} e^{-a^2} \, da = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{1/2} e^{-a^2} \, da.$$
And since from the integral representation for the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) which is given by
$$\text{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \, dt,$$
one has
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \text{erf} \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ),$$
as expected.

Answer (score 2):

*Following Sangchul Lee's hint.*
\begin{align}
I:=\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{4}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\int^1_{-1}e^{ixt}e^{-x^2}\,dt\,dx
\end{align}
Since $|e^{ixt}e^{-x^2}|=e^{-x^2}$ the double integral is clearly absolutely convergent so by Tonelli-Fubini we can interchange the integration order to obtain:
\begin{align}
I=\frac{1}{4}\int^{1}_{-1}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{ixt}e^{-x^2}\,dx\,dt=\frac{1}{4}\int^{1}_{-1}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{4}-(x-it/2)^2}\,dx\,dt
\end{align}
where we have completed the square on the last integral. Now by an easy contour integration on a rectangle we get
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{ixt}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt[]{\pi}e^{-t^2/4}
\end{align}
So with substitutation and parity (P) we can conclude:
\begin{align}
I=\frac{\sqrt[]{\pi}}{4}\int^1_{-1}e^{-t^2/4}\,dt\stackrel{\color{red}{u=t/2}}{=}\frac{\sqrt[]{\pi}}{2}\int^{1/2}_{-1/2}e^{-u^2}\,du\stackrel{\color{red}{P}}{=}\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt[]{\pi}}\int^{1/2}_0e^{-u^2}\,du=\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac 12\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Double integral**
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-x^2} d x= & \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\left(\int_0^1 \cos(x y) d y\right) d x \\
= & \int_0^1 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos (x y) d x d y \\
= & \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}} d y \quad \textrm{(See footnote for details)} \\
= & \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_0^1 e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}} d y \\
= & \frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Footnote:
$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos (x y) d x = & \Re\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} e^{x y i} d x \\
= & \Re\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(x-\frac{y}{2} i\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{4}} d x \\
= & e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}} \Re \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(x-\frac{y}{2} i\right)^2} d x \\
= & e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}} \Re\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(1+i \operatorname{erfi}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\right)\right] \\
= & \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}} 
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Feynman’s Trick**

Let’s consider the parameterized integral
$$
I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (a x) e^{-x^2}}{x} d x
$$
Then differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) & =\int_0^{\infty} \cos (a x) e^{-x^2} d x \\
& =\Re \int_0^{\infty} e^{a x i} e^{-x^2} d x \\
& =\Re\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(x-\frac{a}{2} i\right)^2-\frac{a^2}{4}} d x \\
& =e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}}\Re \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(x-\frac{a}{2} i\right)^2} d x \\
& =e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}} \Re\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(1+i \operatorname{erfi}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\right)\right] \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating $I’(a)$ from $a=0$ to $1$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (x) e^{-x^2}}{x} d x =I(1)-I(0) & =\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}} d a =\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$